# Bluetooth Keeps Getting Turned Off at Wake up

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, mouse, suspend, usb

After sometime of my desktop being suspended, if I wake up the machine, bluetooth is turned off. I need to plug a usb mouse to reenable bluetooth via the indicator and then I can use my devices as intended.

I already have enabled and uncommented `AutoEnable` under `Policy` on `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

Any ideas on why or how can I fix this

Comment: Which version of elementary are you using?

Comment: I had the same issue, but it stopped happening after I upgraded all my packages and rebooted recently.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me so far:

Edit `/etc/bluetooth/input.conf` and under section [General], uncomment the line IdleTimeout=0

```
# Set idle timeout (in minutes) before the connection will
# be disconnect (defaults to 0 for no timeout)
IdleTimeout=0
```

Interesting that defaults to 0... but in my computer bluetooth was disconnected after roughly 10 minutes.

After specifically defining "0", I tested with more than 1 hour inactivity.
Also, I switched the USB adaptor from a regular USB port to a USB 2.0 port (it didn't fix the problem before, but since I enabled the IdleTimeout, it's working now).

Hope it helps you too...

Answer (score 0):

Allright, so I found this on the internet. I cannot test this on my own so I can't confirm it as a working solution but it seems to coincide with your issue. You could give it a try.

[Fixing Bluetooth in Ubuntu, Pop!_OS 18.04](https://medium.com/@overcode/fixing-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-pop-os-18-04-d4b8dbf7ddd6)

Comment: Already tried those :/ with no avail. Thanks for the reply :D

Comment: I am so sorry, I hope someone with more knowledge will be able to post a solution, this issue with the usb port has been going on since always on linux systems, such a shame.